# How to choose the outward Normal Unit Vector For a Surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If $\vec{F} = 2y\hat{i} -z\hat{j} + x^2\hat{k}$ and $S$ is the surface of the parabolic cylinder $y^2 =4x$ in first octant bounded by planes $z =4$ and $z =6$ then

Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{S} F.\hat{n}ds$

Now, My main issue  is how can I decide the sign of Normal Vector $\hat{n}$. I am not able to see which direction is positive and which one is negative.

For $y^2 = 4x$ the Normal Unit Vector is given by :

$\hat{n}$ = $\dfrac{2\hat{i} - y\hat{j}}{\sqrt{y^2 + 4}}$. I am confused whether I should take

$\hat{n}$ or  $-\hat{n}$ as the outward normal Unit Vector ?

Can someone help me here please ?

Thank you.

Comment: In which direction does the paraboloid “open?” In which direction does $\hat n$ point at the vertex?

Comment: @amd : Well, y^2 = 4x opens on the positive side of x axis I don't know how can I use this information to get direction of normal vector

Comment: And what about my second question? Answer that and combine those two pieces of information.

Comment: @amd: The normal Vector points towards Positive side of x axis; therefore $\hat{n}$ should be the normal vector                                     Is this correct ?